# CakePHPのFixtureにおいてテーブルの生成が行われない

Tags: cakephp, phpunit

CakePHPv2.5.5でUnitTestを行っています。

**構成**

databases.php

```
public $xxxx = array(
    // ...
);
public $test_xxxx = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/MysqlExportDb',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'database' => 'test',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

Fixture定義

```
class KeywordFixture extends CakeTestFixture
{
    public $useDbConfig = 'test_xxxx';

    public $fields = array(...);

    public $records = array(...);
}
```

テストコード側

```
class ShellTest extends CakeTestCase
{
    public $fixtures = array(
        'plugin.search_export.keyword',
    );
...
```

**現象１**

keywordsテーブルが存在しない状態でテストを実行すると以下のエラーが発生します。

> MissingTableException: Table keywords for model Keyword was not found in datasource test_xxxx.

**現象２**

手動でkeywordsテーブルを作成して実行を行うと、テストが正しく実行された後keywordsテーブルが消滅します。

**質問**

現象２でテーブルが消えていることから何らかの形でFixtureは認識されていると考えています。
しかしテーブルの生成が行われない原因が分かりません。
考えられる原因を教えてください。

https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/ja/development/testing.html#id15

Answer (score 1):

`useDbConfig` を指定されていることから、以下の現象ではないでしょうか。

> 結論:
>   FixtureのuseDbConfigでDataSourceを指定するには、対になるDataSourceが定義されてないと駄目でした。
>   例)
>   $test_hoge = array(/* ... */); なら $hoge = array(/* ... */);
>   が定義されてないと駄目。

CakePHP の $useDbConfig にはまった(備忘録) - nmtysh.log http://nmtysh.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/11/27/005000

Comment: Datasourceの定義はペアになっていることを確認しました。本文に追記しました。